# Google maps api highway vs road distance

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api to calculate the rout from point A to point B.
The 'The DirectionsResult' object is giving me a lot of info regarding distance etc.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults

However, I am interested to know what is the distance (part of the) route is on HIGHWAY roads and what part is in the CITY roads.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of a way to accomplish this using the Google Maps API services.

Comment: Any specific geographic region?  You may be able to match against a known set of highways.  For example, in the United States, you can find lists of the highways - a quick search turned this up http://www.us-highways.com/  but you may be able to find a consolidated database from the bureau of transportation:  https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/  and to test the theory you could try checking the legs that google provides against a regex that checks for "HWY" or "US-" in the name.

Comment: And, if it is in a mobile device, you can use the gps coordinates to limit the search to the highways in their current state and the interstates that run through that state.  This gets a little bit trickier out east where a wrong turn in Delaware puts you in Maryland, but this process could be refined (returning results for nearby states also if mobile user is near edge of state by gps).

Answer (score 6):

There is no way using the API to differentiate between highways and non-highways.

However, you can assume the difference yourself by calculating the speed for each leg in the route.

Meta code:

```
// find meters per second and convert to miles per hour
mph = (route.leg[i].distance.value / route.leg[i].duration.value) * 2.23694
if mph >= 55
    route.leg[i].road = highway
else
    route.leg[i].road = city
```

Obviously this will not work if the results are taking traffic conditions into account.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-simple_highways.html)

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressPolylines: true,
  infoWindow: infowindow,
});
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
    route);
  route();
}

function route() {
  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('to').value,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      renderer.setMap(map);
      renderer.setPanel(panel);
      renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
      console.log(renderer.getDirections());
    } else {
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(null);
    }

  });

}

var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var polylines = [];

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      // find meters per second and convert to miles per hour
      var mph = (steps[j].distance.value / steps[j].duration.value) * 2.23694
      if (mph >= 55) {
        // route.leg[i].road = highway
        color = "#FF0000";
      } else {
        // route.leg[i].road = city
        color = "black";
      }
      console.log("step " + j + " color=" + color + " mph=" + mph + " dist=" + steps[j].distance.value + " meters/time=" + steps[j].duration.value + " seconds");

      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      polylines.push(stepPolyline);
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
      // route click listeners, different one on each step
      google.maps.event.addListener(stepPolyline, 'click', (function(mph) {
        return function(evt) {
          infowindow.setContent("you clicked on the route<br>speed ~= " + mph.toFixed(2) + " mph<br>" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
          infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
          infowindow.open(map);
        }
      }(mph)));
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#panel-wpr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#panel {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
#info {
  padding: 5px;
}
#from,
#to {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.adp-directions {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.time {
  margin: 0;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #CCC;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #3079ED;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4D90FE;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
}
#info div {
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.btn {} #panel-wpr {
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="panel-wpr">
  <div id="info">
    <div>
      <label>from:</label>
      <input id="from" value="New York, NY" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>to:</label>
      <input id="to" value="Philadelphia, PA" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: converts meters per second to miles per hour - added comment to code